# shell script to search a pattern in a directory and output number of find counts

Tags: shell, pattern-matching

I need a Shell script which take two inputs which are

1. main directory where it has to search and
2. pattern to search within main directory all files (.c and .h files)

It has to print number of pattern found in main directory & each sub directory.

```
main dir    --> Total pattern found = 5
  |
  sub dir   --> 3
  |
  sub dir   --> 2
```

Comment: One way to count things is with the `wc` command; e.g. if you can make your search produce one file per line, `wc -l` prints the number of lines (and therefore number of files).

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
#!/bin/sh

grep -rl "$1" . | sed -r 's/\/[^\/]+$//' | sort | uniq -c
```

It works as follows:

- First find the pattern supplied in argument `$1` using `grep`

  - `-r` searches all files in the current directory `.` and all subdirectories
  - `-l` outputs only the `path/filename` of files which have text matching the pattern
- The `filename` is removed from all outputs so only the `path` (i.e., the directory) remains
- The paths are then sorted and counted.

Its output will look like this:

```
      2 .
      3 ./sub_dir1
      1 ./sub_dir2
      6 ./sub_dir2/a_sub_sub_dir
```

The first column is amount of matches of the pattern in a directory, the second column is the name of the directory (`.` is the main directory).

Comment: Hi this worked for me but in shell scripting i have this command as a seperate file but how would i input pattern to this file